# What is the type of 'child'?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-model

I know type of Object and Array. I know how to use and how to create Object and Array but I don't know what's the type of `child` in JavaScript and how to create type of `child`?

This is a chrome console screenshot.

[image: Chrome console 'child' object]

Comment: How did you get that object in the console? The structure and Backbone tags suggest that it is a `Backbone.Model` of some sort.

Comment: yes  im using Backbone.Model ..

Comment: And there is some sort of `console.log(something_you_are_not_showing_us)` behind that output, right?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be an instance of a custom class named `child`.

If you run the following code in Chrome's console:

```
function child() {}
new child();
```

You would see the same output, minus all the properties of `child`:

[image: screenshot]

For what it's work, normally the naming convention is to capitalize the names of constructor functions like `Child`, but it's not technically necessary.

Comment: Thanks I understand.

Answer (score 1):

I concur with [mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41195468/about-javascript-type-of-child#comment69590952_41195468) that this is most likely an instance of a `Backbone.Model`, either directly or indirectly (through a subclass).

The reason you see `child` is due to Backbone's internal machinery. When you use `Backbone.Model.extend`, backbone sets up a constructor for the new class, and this constructor has the name `child`. This is readily visible in the [code for the `.extend` method](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.3.3/backbone.js#L1874).

Getting some sort of useful identifier out of what you get at runtimme is difficult, if not downright impossible. I've taken the habit of using `__classname__` as a field in which I plunk the name of the class. It is then visible on the `__proto__` field of the object I'm inspecting. I use this only for debugging purposes. Here's an example at the Chrome console:

[image: Chrome console example]

Answer (score 1):

As @mu is too short [correctly guessed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41195468/about-javascript-type-of-child#comment69590952_41195468) from looking at the object properties, it was an instance of [`Backbone.Model`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model).  You could create another instance of the same object (class) like this, providing you knew correct constructor arguments:

```
new child.constructor(...);
```

You could also use the model (class) in a new collection, although you had access just to a model instance:

```
new MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: child.constructor,
  ...
});
```

As @Louis [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41200280/623816), it is not possible to get a reasonable (class) name out of an object instance, unless you put some name to the object prototype yourself.  I often need some initialization code in my models and instead of putting it to the [`initialize`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor) method, I *declare a **named constructor** explicitly* and put the initialization code there.  Like the function named `MyModel` here:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  constructor: function MyModel(attributes, options) {
    Backbone.Model.prototype.constructor.call(this, attributes, options);
    ...
  }
});
```

You can see the object (class) name in Chrome developer tools like this:

```
var Car = Backbone.Model.extend({
  constructor: function Car(attributes, options) {
    Backbone.Model.prototype.constructor.call(this, attributes, options);
  }
});

var Truck = Car.extend({
  constructor: function Truck(attributes, options) {
    Car.prototype.constructor.call(this, attributes, options);
  }
});
```

[image: Truck object instance]

String properties like `__classname___` will be available unchanged in minified code too.  Named constructors will be available only in non-minified code.  If you still needed to see meaningful constructor names after minifying the code, you would have to [exclude them from mangling](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#mangler-options).